# Class name of Program Manager

Tags: java, winapi

I want the HWND of Program Manager. By using the FindWindow the HWND of the window can be found. I have searched in the internet, But I couldn't find the class name.

```
HWND hwndProgMan = User32Extra.INSTANCE.FindWindowEx(User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow(),
                null,    
               ClassName,
               "Program Manager");
```

What is the class name of Program Manager(Windows 7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window class of the Program Manager window is `"Progman"`. This information can be obtained readily using a tool such as Spy++.